# Why does the play store require multiple account login to display my apps in the Google play store

Tags: google-play-store, google-account

I recently changed my 2nd gmail account password.

When I open the play store to check my apps it gave an error:

[image: After clicking my apps in the play store it gave an error-Authentication required .You need to sign in to your Account.]
<sup>Authentication required. You need to sign in to your account. (click image for larger variant)</sup>

Whereas I have already logged in my first Google account  then why does it require the second account to be logged in when I haven't used this account any time for any Android apps till date.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy to answer – let me use an example:

I add your Google account as my secondary. Now I log in with my primary. Would you be happy if I wouldn't have to authenticate for the secondary now? That would enable me to do all kind of stuff "on behalf of you".

So, putting it in short terms: Security concerns. Whether you have logged in with the second account from any apps or not doesn't matter – that account holds personal data, which must be protected.

Comment: I don't get it I have an account a@gmail.com for which i download apps and have an account b@gmail.com which i only used for checking mails in gmail app(i.e a is both checkng mails in  gmail app and download,whereas b is only for checking mails). Now as you say that for security concerns that both the accounts a and b are required for the play store.Previously it was only a single account required to login but now it why does it require two accounts wasn't there any security issue before when the Play store had only a single account access?

Comment: Authorization for Google Services is kind of "single sing-in" AFAIK. Obviously the *Playstore* app checks all configured accounts. Using b@gmail.com for Gmail (or any other Google service), you'll have to sign within that anyway. If you wouldn't use it, you hadn't configured it – I'd guess that's the logic behind it.